# RouterJs how to trigger initial route

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history, routerjs

I'm using [RouterJs](http://haithembelhaj.github.io/RouterJs/) to handle my history push state routes. How can I trigger the initial route if the user visits the route directly in their browser?

The route handler gets executed if I do `router.navigate('/some-route')` from another route, but if I visit `/some-route` directly, the handler for that route does not execute.

My JS:

```
var router = new Router();
router.route('/some-route', function () {
    console.log('hello some route');
});
```

If I load the page directly to `/some-route` and have my console open, I am not seeing "hello some route". I've tried doing `router.navigate(window.location.pathname)` but router won't do anything b/c it's not a change in the url, i.e., I'm already on `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: No, not yet . I have a hack that just runs once on initial page load that parses the current url and calls the appropriate function.